# Next.js app takes 33 seconds to load. What could make it THAT slow?

Tags: next.js

I'm almost done with my first ever Next.js app.

Dev was always somewhat slow to load, but production is absolutely ridiculous.

On first load it takes 30+ seconds for the home page to render.

I've seen really slow sites take 5-10 seconds, but what could I possibly be doing wrong that would lead to 30 second load times?

Is prefetch a huge performance killer?

Comment: [Jan Píša](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12862815) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66012602) saying "It might relate to this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12797"

Answer (score 11):

### Finding the bottleneck:

First of all you need to find out what is making your site slow.
For that I recommend [lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) or the network tab of your development tools.

### Common developer mistakes:

#### A. Development instead production mode:

Next.js has two modes. The development mode (`next dev`) is pretty slow, since a lot of development tools are executed and shipped.

To run your app in production mode first build it with `next build` and then start it with `next start`.

#### B. Included too much code:

Sometimes developers include gigantic npm modules or even modules that only have been build for node.js into next.js.

Finding these modules is actually pretty easy thanks to the [`@next/bundle-analyzer` package](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer).

#### C. Cold Serverless instance:

If you are running your next.js instance on a serverless provider keep in mind that it may take some time to start the serverless instance. Especially if you have a free plan.

Comment: I have the same issue, i am using NEXT js with Netlify and initial build takes longer than it should. I suspect the Cold serverless instance could be a reason for this too

Comment: github repo links for bundle size analyzers do not work